# .htaccess for mobile redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

In the past I have used the script version of redirecting based off of screen size which I'm running into problems with now due to the varying screen sizes in mobile devices these days. Below is the entirety of my .htaccess script, yet my site does not want to redirect. I've tried everything that I can think of to make this work. Do I have a bug? Is using .htaccess even valid either?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/http://m.bayarearetractablescreen.com/.$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.)$ /http://m.bayarearetractablescreen.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could spot a couple of fixes (quantifier after the dots, spurious end of string matcher $, a trailing slash in the last row).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/http://m.bayarearetractablescreen.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.bayarearetractablescreen.com/ [L,R=302]
```

This: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.bayarearetractablescreen.com$` would be a better alternative for line 2.

FYI: you may want to look [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) for updated rules for your purpose.